# php escape string to be correct URL and filename

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string. I need to escape it so it can be a correct URL part and filename (for Linux and Windows) in the same time and URL string should be === filename string. Illegal characters can be replaced or removed.

For example, I have string 'test_?string^my:'. As a result of function work I should receive something like 'test_stringmy', so string 'test_stringmy' can be used in URL and filename in the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = 'test_?string^my:';
$output = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $input));
```

Output:

```
string 'test_stringmy' (length=13)
```

Comment: Good solution, I just added strtolower to $output - strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/', '', str_replace(' ', '_', $input)));